# Can't add Firebase FCM for notifications on my app (SDK Android 5.0). Why?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Using LTS Android Studio, I made an app with the SDK of Android 5.0. I connected the app with Firebase but on step 2 of "Add FCM to your app", does not work. In fact, it does not do anything.

Trying to add `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.8'` on `build.gradle`, doesn't help either. Throws a compilation error. I have to use `classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.8'` for it to compile properly, but when I launch the notification on Firebase, it does not receive it.

I indeed added the Internet permission on the manifest. Doesn't work either.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I was adding the library to the wrong place + Firebase takes some minutes to send the notification.

Answer (score 0):

Because google is end support of android 5 lollipop.You need to add sdk 21 means android naugat android 7 least requirement to use latest sdk in android devices.

Comment: Seems like I was adding the FCM library on the wrong place. Now the library is added properly but can't get the notification to work.

Comment: Fixed. Seems like Firebase takes a lot of time to send the notification. When I say a lot it's a lot (more than 3 minutes). Thanks anyways!